# How can I fix my swap partion?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, windows, dual-boot, swap

So a couple of months ago I installed, on my computer, dual boot so I could have windows and ubuntu at the same time. I had some struggles because my PC is designed with UEFI support (Model: ASUS VivoBook S15). However I made it work, but I only had 6 Mb for my swap partition! Now my PC sometimes freezes for no reason, and I have to reboot. I think the problem is that partition. Does anyone know how I can extend my swap partition?

[image]

Comment: You can try to create a swapfile, activate it and add it to your `/etc/fstab` . Details here : https://linuxize.com/post/create-a-linux-swap-file/

Comment: If you want/need a partition as opposed to a file, then reside the root partition (you will have to use a live distro, MS can't do it, not without some 3rd party app, and you can't do it when it is online).

Answer (score 1):

Use `sudo swapoff /dev/sda6` to stop using it for swapping, then you can resize/move/rearrange the swap partition any way you like.

If you resize the swap partition, or completely recreate it in a different location, you might have to run `sudo mkswap /dev/sda<whatever>` on it afterwards, unless GParted already does that for you. Then just edit your `/etc/fstab` if necessary (since the UUID of the swap partition *will* change on `mkswap`, or the device name may change if you recreate the swap partition elsewhere), and run `sudo swapon -a` to activate it again.

Comment: I would not try to resize it, there is Microsoft stuff in the way, and it is sure to break.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Hibernation? Then you *must* have a swap partition equal in size to your RAM chip size.

If you don't, boot from Windows of a Linux Live USB and delete /dev/sda6 because 4MB is more trouble than it's worth.

Then. boot back into Linux and [create a swap file](https://itsfoss.com/create-swap-file-linux/) in your root partition, because your system is [guaranteed to be unstable without it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/190521/49368). How much? [See here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/467498/49368).